# Virtual Machine Manager missing "Allocate Entire Drive Now" check-box when creating new VM

Tags: kvm-virtualization

In Unity 16.04, when creating a new VM, the option for Allocate Entire Drive Now is missing, meaning that when creating a new machine, the entire drive is allocated, i.e. waisted physical drive space.  It is not missing in Xubuntu 14.04.04.  Any where to turn this off (other than command-line (not that this is a problem))?

Answer (score 0):

Actually qcow2 image that Virtual Machine Manager creates is sparse file.
It looks like for example 20GB file to ls -l but du on freshly created file will show it to be less than 3MB.